# Create a script to update the SKU and set SKU using CSV

Tags: magento2, sku, script

How To Create a script For Update Product SKU Using Custom Script.

Answer (score 1):

1. First create CSV and placed in the root folder (sku.csv) https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZrat.png

   2. Create a script in the root directory name script.php

      ```
      <?php 

      use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
      require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
      $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
      $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

      $state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
      $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
      $fileCsv = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\File\Csv');
      $moduleReader = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader');
      $directoryList  = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
      $file = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File');

       $filePath = "sku.csv"; 
       if (file_exists($filePath)) {
          $rows = $fileCsv->getData($filePath);
          $count = 0;
          $successSku = [];
          $failedSku = [];
            foreach($rows as $row) {
              if($count > 0) {
                $oldSku  = (isset($row[0])) ? $row[0] : "";
                 $newSku  = (isset($row[1])) ? $row[1] : "";
           if($oldSku && $newSku) {
          $productId = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getIdBySku($oldSku);
          if($productId) {
              try {
                  $productFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
                  $product = $productFactory->create()->load($productId);
                  $product->setSku($newSku);
                  $product->save();
                  $successSku[$newSku] = $newSku;
              }
              catch (\Exception $e) {
                  echo "Cannot retrieve products from Magento: ".$e->getMessage()."<br>"; 
              }
          }else {
              $failedSku[$oldSku] = $oldSku;  
               }
           }
         }
             $count++;
          }
         }
         echo "Sucessfully updated SKU";
      ```